# strncat undefined behaviour on particular number

Tags: c++, string

I know the size of destination is small so that my code not working correctly but all I want to know when I put 35 in destination character print in infinite loop why it become infinite only when I put 35 in other number it crash or work in bigger number.

I am using Windows 7 Code Block with `gcc`.

```
   using namespace std;

     int main()
       {
          char dest[35] = "This is an example";//when put another number it work     or crash but at this number it print infinite number of character why what is logic
          char src[50] = " to show working of strncat() this is not added";

       strncat(dest, src, 29);
          cout << dest ;
        return 0;

         }
```

Comment: i mean "This is an example to show working of strncat()" string print infinite times

Comment: You write out of bounds of `dest`, that means anything can happen

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. There is no logic.

Comment: Newbies (and noobs) often expect there to be a logic to their bugged programs. This is a mistake, most bugged programs have *undefined behaviour* which means you cannot reason about how they should behave.

Comment: `strncat` is not a "safe" replacement for `strcat`. To see why, read about what `strncat` does when the size is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 17 characters plus a null byte in the initialized `dest` array.

When you call `strncat(dest, src, 29)`, you say "it is safe to add 29 extra characters to `dest`" — which is nonsense as you can only add 17 characters without overflowing the array.

You invoked undefined behaviour.  That means the program can work, or crash, or go into an infinite loop, and all those behaviours are OK because undefined behaviour doesn't have to behave in any specific way.

Note that `strncat(dst, sizeof(dst), very_long_string)` is a boundary error, even if `dst[0] == '\0'`.  You can use `strncat(dst, sizeof(dst)-1, very_long_string)` if the destination is empty.  (The very long string is any string longer than `sizeof(dst) - 1`, of course.)